# Rails/Slim_Dynamic data tag attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, slim-lang

https://github.com/slim-template/slim-rails/issues/168

How could I convert below erb to slim?

ERB code

```
<div class="click" <%= love_type ? "data-review=#{target}" : "data-recommend=#{target}" %>
                                   data-logined='<%= sth%>'></div>
```

I tried...

```
.click[data-logined="#{sth}"
      love_type ? data-review="#{target}" : data-recommend="#{target}"]
```

and

```
.click data-logined="#{sth}" love_type ? data-review="#{target}" : data-recommend="#{target}"
```

But not work...

How could I do this writing simple DRY code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`.click *{ data: { logined: "#{sth}", review: "#{love_type ? target : nil }", recommend:"#{love_type ? nil : target}" } }`

Or you can use a helper method to return `data` as a hash:

`.click *{ data: as_a_hash(love_type) }`

helper_method:

```rb
def as_a_hash(args)
  { logined: "#{sth}", review: "#{args ? target : nil }", recommend:"#{args ? nil : target}" }
end
```